# Regex to match string after similar words

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am trying to parse the log file below; however I am a bit stuck on figuring out how to match the results after all the "Step=Number".

> Step=10 , Step=11 , Step=12 , Step=13 , Step=14 , Step=15 , Step=16 , Step=18 , Step=17 , Step=20 , Step=19 , Step=25 , Step=21 , Step=26 , Step=28 , Step=24 , Step=22 , Step=23 , Step=27 , Step=30 , Step=29 , Step=35 , Step=34 , Step=32 , Step=31 , Step=38 , Step=37 , Step=36 , Step=50 , Step=45 , Step=48 , Step=41 , Step=52 , Step=42 , Step=57 , Step=65 , Step=61 , Step=62 , Step=64 , Step=54 , Step=53 , Step=59 , Step=63 , Step=84 , Step=71 , SelectedAuthenticationIdentityStores=paddedvalue, NetworkDeviceName=exampledevice, NetworkDeviceGroups=Update Source:All Sources:ACS, NetworkDeviceGroups=Device Type:All Device Types:Wireless, NetworkDeviceGroups=Location:All Locations, ServiceSelectionMatchedRule=Rule-1, IdentityPolicyMatchedRule=Default

I was thinking about matching after the combination of: \d\s\,\s

The ideal goal is to match the following:

> SelectedAuthenticationIdentityStores=paddedvalue, NetworkDeviceName=exampledevice, NetworkDeviceGroups=Update Source:All Sources:ACS, NetworkDeviceGroups=Device Type:All Device Types:Wireless, NetworkDeviceGroups=Location:All Locations, ServiceSelectionMatchedRule=Rule-1, IdentityPolicyMatchedRule=Default

I tried the following regex: `\d\s\\,\s(.*)` but that matches everything after the first Step=Number (Step=10)

Comment: is `(?: ?Step=\d+ ,)*\s(.*)` ok?

Comment: `/(Step=\d+\s*,\s*)+(.*)/` should do it. `\2` would give you the desired string.

Comment: How about removing the `(Step=\d+\s,\s)` pattern with nothing, so you can get the last part of string easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another .* in the beginning of your existing pattern to greedily consume all but the last possible match:

```
.*\d\s,\s(.*)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Oc7jUK/1

Alternatively, you can use a positive lookbehind pattern to ensure that the match is preceded by a `\d\s,\s`, and a negative lookahead pattern to ensure that there's no more `\d\s,\s` that follows:

```
(?<=\d\s,\s)(?!.*\d\s,\s).*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Oc7jUK/2

Comment: I like this answer and would it be possible to reduce the number of steps consumed by the regex engine?

Comment: I've updated my answer to match precisely what you look for then.

Comment: I think your initial solution is the best one in terms of regex computation time and accuracy. 

.*\d\s,\s(.*)

Comment: I think so too. Did the second solution only since you asked for it. I've updated the answer with the first solution included then.

Answer (score 0):

why not using a regex that match all after `SelectedAuthenticationIdentityStores` like `SelectedAuthenticationIdentityStores.*` or `\w{5,}.*`

```js
const regex = /SelectedAuthenticationIdentityStores.*/g;
const text = `Step=10 , Step=11 , Step=12 , Step=13 , Step=14 , Step=15 , Step=16 , Step=18 , Step=17 , Step=20 , Step=19 , Step=25 , Step=21 , Step=26 , Step=28 , Step=24 , Step=22 , Step=23 , Step=27 , Step=30 , Step=29 , Step=35 , Step=34 , Step=32 , Step=31 , Step=38 , Step=37 , Step=36 , Step=50 , Step=45 , Step=48 , Step=41 , Step=52 , Step=42 , Step=57 , Step=65 , Step=61 , Step=62 , Step=64 , Step=54 , Step=53 , Step=59 , Step=63 , Step=84 , Step=71 , SelectedAuthenticationIdentityStores=paddedvalue, NetworkDeviceName=exampledevice, NetworkDeviceGroups=Update Source:All Sources:ACS, NetworkDeviceGroups=Device Type:All Device Types:Wireless, NetworkDeviceGroups=Location:All Locations, ServiceSelectionMatchedRule=Rule-1, IdentityPolicyMatchedRule=Default`
console.log(text.match(regex))
```

Comment: i am just trying to give a visual  example

Comment: It is not necessarily the case that the "SelectedAuthenticationIdentityStores" attribute occurs after the "Step=Number". Therefore, I cannot create a static match on a specific word. Thanks for contributing @G.aziz